# GoogleMap won't load detailed map until user interaction

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I'm writing an application on android that will show a map from google maps. When I start the app, the map is centered on the current location. When I use `animateCamera`, I can see the zoom-in animation from the whole world until it focuses on current location.

The problem is that I need to touch the map to get the map to display at the zoom level I expected.

Here is what I get before I touch the screen :
[Before touch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnk4M.jpg)

Here is what I get after having touch the screen :
[After touch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cianP.jpg)

If I touch the screen, the image will remain fine, until I drive a few hundred meters and then it's again unuseable. Sometimes the image appears, but it's only 1 or 2 times per 10km.

Here is how I move the camera inside `LocationListener::onLocationChanged` :

```
float zoom = 19.0f;

LatLng target = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
// moving car marker
m_locationMarkerG.setPosition(target);
m_locationMarkerG.setRotation(location.getBearing());

// tilting camera depending on speed
float tilt = Math.min(90, location.getSpeed()*10);
m_mapViewG.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition.builder().zoom(zoom).bearing(location.getBearing()).
        target(target).tilt(tilt).build()));
```

What could I try to solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you call m_mapViewG.onCreate() before using ?

Comment: no, there is no such method on a com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution :

animateCamera MUST be called from the main looper. The LocationListener is called from another thread (sensor's thread).

So the code become :

```
final float zoom = 19.0f;

final LatLng target = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

// tilting camera depending on speed
final float tilt = Math.min(90, location.getSpeed()*10);

m_handler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // moving car marker
        m_locationMarkerG.setPosition(target);
        m_locationMarkerG.setRotation(location.getBearing());

        // moving camera
        m_mapViewG.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition.builder().zoom(zoom).bearing(location.getBearing()).target(target).tilt(tilt).build()));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old problem but I faced too.

I fix this problem with this:

```
 binding.root.doOnLayout {
      map?.animateCamera(camera)
 }
```